# JQuery - selecting first instance of a div class id on page

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to select the first instance of a a div id of the form volume_header_+id# that appears on a page. If I explicitly put the id#, for example `volume_header_123`, the code works.  But when I try to replace that with a generic selector to select the first occurrence no mater what the id# is, everything breaks.

```
<div class="volume_wrapper">
  <div id="volume_header_123" class="volume_header">
    …
  </div> //end volume_header_123
  <div id="volume_issues_123" class="volume_issues" style="display: block;">
    <div class="issue_wrapper">
      <div id="issue_header_123_6" class="issue_header">
        …
      </div> //end issue_header_123_6
      <div id="issue_toc_123_6" class="issue_toc" style="display: none;">
        <div class="toc_item">
          …
        </div> //end toc_item
      </div> //end issue_toc_123_6
    </div> //end issue_wrapper
  </div> //end volume_issues_123
</div> //end volume_wrapper
```

The following code works properly when explicitly stating the div id, but I need to make it generic so it selects the first occurrence, regardless of the id# appended to the end of `volume_header_` or `volume_issues_`.

```
      jQuery('#volume_header_123').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #cc0000');
      jQuery('#volume_header_123').addClass('selected');
      jQuery('#volume_issues_123').slideDown(50);
```

I have experimented with .eq(0), :first, and several other selectors according to some of the other answer given on this site, but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( ".volume_header" ).first().hide()

This is selecting the first element with the class volume_header and then hide it. Replace the hide call with your required function calls.

As you are using dynamic ids just refer to the first element with the class name instead

Comment: Amazing, this did it! I was just slightly off in the syntax I had tried before... I believe I read elsewhere on here that `.eq(0)` is preferable or better practice/more widely supported than `.first()`, is that true?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure of the benefits of one or the other but if it works then great! Please mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this code, as a child selector:

```
    $('.volume_wrapper > .volume_header');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
$( "div[id^='volume_issues_']" ).first();
```

Check doc for this: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. Attribute starts with selector

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/6wp44kc3/ 
In my example I use:
    `$("p", "div").eq(0).html("ha");` 
I am using eq to select the first paragraph tag with in the scope of the div element. Then I am setting the html of the paragraph tag to ha. Using eq in this way will allow you to select the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative:

```
$($("div").get(0)).hide();
```